# Can't append NaN to python list

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 28, in <module>
    buy.append(np.nan)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nan'
```

Here the code its python 3

```
import fxcmpy
import socketio
from pylab import plt
import numpy as np
from finta import TA

TOKEN='xxxx'
con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token=TOKEN, log_level='error', server='real', log_file='log.txt')
#print(con.get_instruments())
data = con.get_candles('US30', period='D1', number=250)
con.close()
df1=data[['askopen','askhigh', 'asklow', 'askclose']]
plt.style.use('seaborn')
np=df1.to_numpy()
df2=df1.rename(columns={'askopen':'open','askhigh':'high','asklow':'low','askclose':'close'})
dfhma=TA.HMA(df2,14)
pr1=dfhma.shift(1)
pr2=dfhma.shift(2)
buy=[]
sell=[]
i=0
flag=''
for item in dfhma:
    if item > pr1[i] and item > pr2[i] and flag!=1:
        flag=1
        buy.append(item)
    else:
        buy.append(np.nan)
    if item < pr1[i] and item < pr2[i] and flag!=0:
        flag=0
        sell.append(item)
    else:
        sell.append(np.nan)
    i=i+1
print(buy)
print('buy len='+str(len(buy)))
mk=[]
for item in dfhma:
    print(item)
plt.plot(dfhma)
plt.scatter(dfhma.index,buy,marker='^',color='g')
plt.scatter(dfhma.index,sell,marker='v',color='r')
plt.show()
```

Search Google/Stackoverflow nothing was found and change nan to NaN,NAN still got the same error guessing its newbie error Help !! Just try to add NaN to the list as a buy/sell signal and it doesn't work what could be wrong here ?

Comment: The error isn't in the `append` itself, but in creating object to be appended, `np.nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 14 `np=df1.to_numpy()` you reassigned variable `np` from a package to a numpy array. So when you called `np.nan` it was searching `nan` from the numpy ndarray instance, not the package.
Change the variable to any other name and it will work fine.